# Execute Snowflake Procedure in Matilion

Tags: matillion

I'm trying to execute Snowflake Stored Procedure in Matilion Using Sql Script component.

But i'm getting error as Unknown user defined function.

Can someone help me to call the procedure using Matilion Job.

[image]

Thank You !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a name resolution error. Snowflake does not recognize the name of the stored procedure. You will see the same generic error message when trying to call a procedure that really does not exist...

[image]

You most likely need to

- qualify the procedure name with a database and a schema
- put the names inside double-quotes if they are case sensitive.

In the [Matillion stored procedure article](https://www.matillion.com/resources/blog/using-stored-procedures-with-matillion) there is an example `CALL "${environment_database}"."${examples_schema}"."audit"('START', ${run_history_id}, NULL)`